# Which ancient hero is most associated with confronting the unknown?

Tags: myth-identification, archetypes

I came across this quote from Jordan Peterson:

> Well what would you want to be king? You could say king of the world or king of your own soul: What do you wanna subordinate yourself to. How 'bout your heroic willingness to encounter the unknown and articulate it and share that with people. There's no nobler vision than that
>
> https://youtu.be/nVlCsILzAXw?t=737

Peterson is an exponent of archetypes and would surely expect to see heroes confronting unknown dangers to win great rewards throughout mythology.

My question is: **Does anyone have a sense of which ancient figure is the best example of a 'willingness to confront the unknown'?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "Divine Comedy" ("Divina Comedia") by Dante Alighieri, while exploring Hell("inferno" section) , chapter 26 ("canto" 26), lines 85-142 ("versi" 85-142)": Odysseus last journey is described.

He was getting older, but it's desire for exploration and adventure was not so, he left for a one way trip:

[link to paragraph](http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/2308#Dante_0045-01_EN_3620)

> nor fondness for my son, nor pious reverence for my agèd father,
>   nor ev’n the bounden love which should have cheered Penelope, could
>   overcome within me
>   **the eagerness I had to gain experience both of the world, and of the vice and worth of men**; but forth I put upon the deep and open sea
>   with but a single ship, and with that little company, by whom I had
>   not been deserted.

and one paragraph later he gives a speech to his travel companions:

[link to paragraph](http://oll.libertyfund.org/titles/2308#Dante_0045-01_EN_3643).

> And then I said: ‘O brothers, ye who now have through a hundred
>   thousand perils reached the West, to this so short a waking-time still
>   left your senses, will not to refuse experience of that world behind
>   the sun which knows not man! Bethink you of the seed whence ye have
>   sprung; for ye were not created to lead the life of stupid animals,
>   but manliness and knowledge to pursue.’